# waiting for users response in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I created an alert:

```
var a = 0 // default
let userAction = UIAlertController(title: "Select", message: "Select an action", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

userAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "action 1", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    a = 1
}))

userAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "action 2", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    a = 2
}))

present(userAction, animated: true, completion: nil)

let resp = Just.get("http://localhost/\(a)").text
return resp
```

and after this code i'm sending a request with a parameter(a) but request is sent before choosing an action.
how can i wait till user choose and action from alert?

Comment: where is your sending request function ? when are you calling it ? Add more code please.

Comment: After tapping the button only, the action will be performed

Comment: @sharadchauhan edited question

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `call function` below the `present` call. Move it to your alert button action closure

```
var a = 0 // default
let userAction = UIAlertController(title: "Select", message: "Select an 
 action", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

userAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "action 1", style: .default, 
handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    a = 1
    // Call function here
}))

userAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "action 2", style: .cancel, 
handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    a = 2
    // Call function here
}))

present(userAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: also tried this one,but when i'm trying to do "return"  where you put a comment i'm getting an error "unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Comment: just call the function and add return statement within it

Comment: @Michael can you upload your full code, what's return?

Comment: @QuocNguyen it's returning a response which i get on my get request

Comment: @Michael move your `let resp = Just.get("http://localhost/\(a)").text` to the new function, you don't need to return anything

Comment: @QuocNguyen i need because i'm calling this function like this:
`toast(myFuncWithAlert)`

so i really need a return value :(

p.s toast function displays a toast message

Answer (score 0):

you can use semaphore to wait process until get signal.

Have a look at this tutorial https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb, it's for GCD, but we can use it for main queue also.

Simply create `let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)` , then `semaphore.wait()` - wait until its get signal through `semaphore.signal()`.

Have a look at tutorial link for more information.

Comment: Isn’t it bad to call wait() on main thread? It can freeze the user interface that runs on it. Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791315/can-i-call-on-semaphore-wait-main-thread

Comment: You can still achieve the same mechanism for main thread by using a notification coupled with a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Declare typealias on top of class like

```
import UIKit
typealias Request = ((_ value:String) -> ())
```

then your method :-

```
func showPopup( completion:@escaping Request)  {

    var a = 0 // default
    let userAction = UIAlertController(title: "Select", message: "Select an action", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    userAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "action 1", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        a = 1
        let resp = Just.get("http://localhost/\(a)").text
        completion(resp)
    }))

    userAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "action 2", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        a = 2
        let resp =  Just.get("http://localhost/\(a)").text
        completion(resp)
    }))

    self.present(userAction, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

and call your method where you want like this:-

```
self.showPopup{ (value) in

     print(value)
}
```

Comment: that's was my only variant,but i thought that there is another solution

Comment: @Michael yes there is another idea you can use completion block for this.

Comment: can you please show an example? i'm not very familiar with swift yet

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
 let alertView = UIAlertController.init(title: "Enviado com sucesso!", message: "O seu bilhete foi enviado com sucesso", preferredStyle: .alert)

 let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
        //the Code you place here Will be called after user Select an action
 }
 alertView.addAction(OKAction)
 self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```