# can I call on semaphore.wait() main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a method which gives me photo auth status.

```
func photosAuthorizationStatus() -> PHAuthorizationStatus {
        var authStatus = PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) in
            authStatus = status
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        semaphore.wait()
        return authStatus
    }
```

I am calling this method in viewDidAppear of a ViewController , but Application is not freezing.

But if I call semaphore.wait when I ask mainQueue explicitly Application is freezing.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
semaphore.wait()

}
```

// Above code will freeze the application.

Can I know the reason ?

Comment: You must have already granted permission so the call to `requestAuthorization` returns immediately and the semaphore is signaled without any obvious freeze.

Comment: ⚠️️ If you do this in the main thread, the whole app will freeze ⚠️️ This article may help you ... https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb

Comment: is there any simple way to get photo auth status if not requested and already requested scenarios.

Comment: Use completion handlers, not semaphores.

Answer (score 2):

In your title, you ask:

> can I call on semaphore.wait() main thread?

You should avoid blocking the main thread for any reason. Whether `wait` for semaphores or dispatch groups, or even synchronously dispatching (e.g., [`sync`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync)) of anything more than a few milliseconds. You risk having the watchdog process kill your app if you do this at the wrong time, and it results in a horrible UX.

---

You then go on to ask:

> ```
> DispatchQueue.main.async {
>    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
>    semaphore.wait()
> }
> ```
>
> Above code will freeze the application.
>
> Can I know the reason

That code says “block the main thread waiting for a `signal` on this semaphore”. So, until that `signal` arrives, the main thread will be blocked. But the main thread should never be blocked because it services, amongst other things, the UI, and your app will freeze if you deadlock the main thread.

Bottom line, never block the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Create completion closure in method which will call after successful request authorisation completed. See following code.

Make sure your have added permission key `"Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description"` in Info.plist file.

```
func photosAuthorizationStatus(completion: @escaping (PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) in
        completion(status)
    }
}
```

***Use:***

```
self.photosAuthorizationStatus { (status) in
    // use your status here
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This I know but my code is also not freezing the application if i request also can I know the reason?

Comment: @santhosh It's not freezing because you already granted permission. Delete the app and reinstall so the permission needs to be asked again and your app will freeze.

Comment: Nope for first time also it is not freezing.

Comment: @santhosh, It's working as you can see my updated answer. Application ask for permission first time and freeze until user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but it may be useful for others, since nobody explained the real issue here.

Calling semaphore.wait() decreases the counting semaphore. If the counter becomes smaller than zero, wait() blocks the main queue until you signal the semaphore.

Now, you invoke semaphore.signal() in the completion closure, which happens to execute on the main queue. But the main queue is blocked, so it won't call semaphore.signal(). wait() and signal() will wait for each other for eternity -> **a guaranteed classic deadlock!**

Forget the semaphore, and refactor the photosAuthorizationStatus() method to return the result via a closure, as suggested by Sagar Chauhan.